# Loading .net reference library DLL at runtime for performance purpose

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, devexpress

My application uses DevExpress that have a lot of component's dll.
They are already loaded when they are needed. (So the DevExpress's team already do that).

The problem is that my main window (in **WPF**) have a lot of their controls so when i use `new MainWindow()` it hangs for ten seconds or more for loading all the necessary DLL.

Before this main window i have a loading window that connect to a database and do other things. Because i know what controls will be used in the main window, can i load with a progress bar (maybe in another thread?) the referenced dll so that the user can see a progress and will not think the program crashed/is blocked?

Thank you.

Comment: Just create the `MainWindow` while the loading window is displayed on the screen. Avoid making it visible until the loading is complete. At that point, hide the loading window and show the `MainWindow`. WinForms has an excellent splash screen class built into it that can do all of this automatically; I don't know about WPF, but it might have something similar.

Comment: Yes but i would like to show some progress. Because also if the app will not hang, it will remain at the some point (the progress) because the MainWindow is not loaded yet.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199093/devexpress-controls-for-wpf-load-time for an answer from the DevExpress team.